# How to colour different border in d3 map

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a D3.js map. I want to split 3 areas and add a different color border. I have tried to add svg path on map but mouseover and mouseout was fail. What can I do?

The image is what I expect.

[image]

```
d3.json("map/country.json", function(error, map) {
    deleteMap();
    if (error) return console.error(error);
    projection = d3.geo.mercator().center([121,23,5]).scale(40000).translate([mapX,mapY]);
    path = d3.geo.path().projection(
        projection
        );
    features = topojson.feature(map, map.objects.country).features;
    d3.select("#svg").selectAll("path").data(features).enter().append("path").attr("d",path)
    .attr("fill",colorDefault).attr("class","area")
    .on({
        "mouseover": function(d){
            d3.select(this).classed("active", true);
            var x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
            var y = d3.mouse(this)[1];
            mouseInInformation(x,y,d.properties.C_Name)
        },
        "mouseout":  function(){
            d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
            var x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
            var y = d3.mouse(this)[1];
            mouseOutInformation(x,y);
        },

    }).call(zoom);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you taken:

*I have tried to add svg path on map but mouseover and mouseout was fail.*

Is the correct approach.

If you don't want the mouse event on the path then set the css attribute
`pointer-events: none;` on the path, it will not take the mouse events.